# i'm trying to access a classes ivars from a obj-c block that's defined as part of the class. what don't i understand here?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
//class definition
@interface class1 : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *array ;
    void (^test)() ;
}
@property( nonatomic,assign ) NSMutableArray *array  ;
@property( nonatomic,readonly ) void (^test)()  ;
@end

// implementation

@implementation class1

@synthesize array ;
@synthesize test ;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil] ;
    test = ^ () {
        NSLog(@"length of array = %d",(int)[array count]);
    } ;
    return self;
}

// from main

    class1 *c = [[class1 alloc] init] ;

    c.test();
```

---

as long as the function "c.test()" accesses simple ivars, i.e. char, int, etc. c.test() executes and returns cleanly. i try to access an obj-c object, i get exceptions. 
what am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BJ's correct that you need to follow the rules of memory management, but in this case, the answer *does* have to do with blocks.

As your code currently stands, the normal property of `array` will work *until the current autorelease pool drains*.  If you alloc/init one of these "class1" objects and immediately attempt to use the `array` property, it will work (because no autorelease pool will have been drained between the initialization of the object and the time at which you attempt to access the array).

However, once you put the block in there, this is no longer the case.  When you declare a block using the `^{ ... }` syntax, this block is allocated in the current frame on the call stack.  When you `return` from the init method, the current frame is popped.  The block ivar still holds a memory address, but a block no longer exists at that address.  It was destroyed when the stack frame was removed.

The way to avoid this is to copy the block off of the stack and onto the heap, and then use *that* block instead:

```
test = [^{  NSLog(@"block!"); } copy];
```

Comment: I would be surprised (and dismayed) if Build and Analyze didn't catch this.  If it didn't, please file a bug (OP).

Comment: i think i understand. when i assigned the block, i created an object on the stack, so i need to copy it off the stack to properly assign it to the "test" ivar. copying will automatically increment the retain count, so need to release it when i'm done with it.

Comment: @bbum just checked in 4.0 and it doesn't catch it. I'm downloading 4.0.1 and will see if it's in there.

Comment: @ron exactly! you'll need to do `[test release]` in your `-dealloc` method.

Comment: @bbum filed as rdar://9230700

Answer (score 2):

You're not retaining the array in your init method, and you're not calling the setter method either. Likewise for the block; if you want your objects to stick around past the duration of the current method, you need to take ownership of them, either by calling your setter methods or calling `retain` (or `copy` in the case of the block).

Your error has nothing to do with blocks, and everything to do with memory management. Note that if you're using garbage collection, you still need to call copy to cause the block to be moved to the heap

Comment: +1 correct in principle, but in this case, the correct answer *does* have to do with blocks.

Comment: Well, I guess that's true. But my point is that you only have this problem if your memory management is wrong. (Though I guess that's not true under GC, so your point stands.)